# Webpack not loading JSON into Javascript

Tags: json, webpack, loader

I'm trying to load a dynamically generated `JSON` file into my `javascript` app - but I keep running into issues.
NOTE: I'm not using `Node.js`, just straight up vanilla javascript.

Everything I read said to do this with `Webpack` and their website clearly states that: `beginning with Webpack version 2.0.0 json loaders are no longer needed.`

Well right now I'm trying the following in my `app.js` file and getting an error:

```
import * as contractArtifact from "../build/contracts/MySmartContract.json"
```

The error is:

```
import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

NOTE: that `MySmartContract.json` file that I'm trying to load is *not* static; it's dynamically generated and has to be loaded anew every time.

I'm very new to `webpack` but I'm pretty sure I've installed every single package that I might need for this - according to the million tutorials I've gone through.
Here's what's in my `package.json` file right now:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "serve": "webpack && node server.js"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/template": "^7.10.4",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "json5-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^5.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
}
...
```

And my `webpack.config.js` file looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/js/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "myCode.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "FinalCode")
    },
    resolve: { 
        extensions: ['.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json']   
    }
};
```

So what exactly needs to be added or tweaked in all this - and how am I finally importing that `.json` file into my `javascript` app? Am I using an `import` statement? A `require` statement? Or something else?

Comment: Have you tried adding the json extension: eg.
`resolve: { extensions: ['.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json']
  }` into your webpack.config.js ?

Comment: OK, I just added the `resolve` line you suggested to my code (I also updated the code in my question above - let me know if that's how I was supposed to add it in?) Cause right now I'm still getting the same error I got before.

Comment: What error are you getting? @Sirab33? It doesn't help if we don't know what's broken? Also you need to add the `loader` configuration to parse JS files. https://github.com/babel/babel-loader <-- see the configuration for your version of Babel and Webpack (https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/)

Comment: @TheLazyChap To answer your question: the error I'm getting is `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module` (note that I've I already indicated this in both the body of my question and in my last comment `"I'm still getting the same error I got before."`) I went ahead and added the `loader` configuration as per your suggestion using the links you provided (thank you!) - but I'm still getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this import inside a function/if or something else? The error seems to suggest that.

Imports need to be static (unless you use dynamic imports that are a promise function) a difference with require that can be used anywhere.

Try putting that line on the top of the file and also rewrite it like this

```
import contractArtifact from "../build/contracts/MySmartContract.json"
```

Comment: To answer your question: no, I'm not doing it inside a function or conditional. As per your suggestions, I put it at the very top of the file - same exact error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your MySmartContract.json to MySmartContract.js and the code inside will be:

```
export const MySmartContract = [{Your json data}]
```

end them import:

```
import { MySmartContract } from "../build/contracts/MySmartContract.js"
```

or try

```
import MySmartContract from "../build/contracts/MySmartContract.js"
```

then MySmartContract will be a JSONObject or JSONArray it depend on your json data

Comment: I'd love to be able to do what you're suggesting, but I can't touch the `json` file or tweak it's code in any way, because it's dynamically generated by a compiler. We're dealing with an `Ethereum smart contract` here, written in `Solidity`. Every time I compile it, it gets re-written and the `json` gets put in the `build` folder automatically. I have no control over it's format and can't add `export const MySmartContract` or anything else into it. (At least not to my knowledge.)